# MVC - Game - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller

I am developing a game for the iPhone.  The game basically animates objects on the screen, allowing a user to click on them.  I am trying to use the MVC pattern.  I have the functionality laid out as such:

Model:
  Holds data about the targets (speed, relative size, image, etc)
  Has timer running that adds targets to the list (should this be in the controller?)

Controller:
  Subscribes to events fired from the model (such as target added)
  Subscribes to events fired from the view (such as target clicked)

View:
  Displays targets

The flow can be as follows:

1. Controller tells Model to start game
2. Model fires timer which says to add a target
3. Controller hears event and passes it to view
4. View adds image to screen (animating it)
5. User clicks on image
6. View fires event which says image was clicked
7. Controller hears event and passes it to model
8. Model removes target from itself

Lastly, I am unsure where to put the animation.  Should the view construct the animation (based off of settings from the model)?

Comment: Looks like you're good.  Yes, the view takes care of the stuff the user sees (like constructing animations), and the controller takes care of the flow of the program (like the timer).

Comment: So are you saying the view should make the animation and the controller manage the timer?  I was going to have the model handle both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider having the view or controller handle the animation so you can take advantage of Cocoa's built-in animation support. For example it would go like this:

1. View queries model for position
2. View adds image to screen at position
3. View queries model for velocity
4. View computes new position after 0.1s and animates image to new position
5. Cocoa fires animation complete event
6. View hears event
7. View computes new position after 0.1s more and animates image to new position

And if targets can change velocity, you have some options. You can have the model fire events for velocity changes, and cancel the animation in progress and start a new one. Or you can just have the view requery the model each time an animation completes, ask for the valid position and velocity, and compute the next position. With the latter there would be some missynchronization between the model and the view, but with updates every 0.1s it wouldn't get too far off. It depends how precise you need to be.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that an animation would be part of a model (or a model within a model), specified by a controller, and rendered by a view.

Here's a good example for the iPhone:

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1969

Comment: I think you could come down either way on that, depending on whether the animation is really a state change in the object (in which case it's model stuff) or just a means of updating the view from one state to a the next (in which case it's view stuff). In a turn-based game like chess, if you were to have the pieces animate from one position to the next then I'd think that was view stuff. In a driving game which animated the wheels turning as the car moves I'd probably expect that to be model stuff.

Comment: Oh Yeah, I agree 100%, it greatly depends on how the animation is to be used.  My answer was just "in general" speak.

Comment: Though, an image is an asset that either needs to be loaded from storage or generated in process so I'd consider the model its home.  Plus, you want to have the ability to easily swap out views that can all render the same model.

Comment: The animation is moving around the image that the user needs to touch.  A lot of its data (such as speed, size, etc) the model needs to know about.

Comment: I guess UIKit itself is a good guide. CoreAnimation is a view technology often used to transition the view from showing one model state to showing another; similarly things like buttons that react to touches animate themselves. However, as you say, any time you're supplying a unique asset - including specifying a unique animation - that's where you'd expect the model to do the work. @user472292: if what happens in the view feeds back into the model, the model should definitely decide what effect that feedback has.